# Colisiones en juego snake c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo el juego de snake en c#, y me están dando problemas las colisiones con las paredes y con la serpiente misma este es el código entero que llevo hasta ahora:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cuc
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Coords
        {
            public int cXanelles;
        }
        public struct CoordsCuc
        {
            public int cX, cY;
            public char direcció;
            public int llargada;
        }

        public struct fruita
        {
            public int x, y, durada, augment, valorNutritiu;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool colisio = false;
            bool final = false;
            int Augment = 0;
            int duradafalsa = 0;
            int[] cucx = new int[1800];
            int[] cucy = new int[1800];


            CoordsCuc cuc = new CoordsCuc();
            cuc.cX = 37;
            cuc.cY = 12;
            cuc.llargada = 4;

            Coords body = new Coords();
            body.cXanelles = 37;

            CoordsCuc Direccions;
            Direccions.direcció = 'W';
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            fruita Fruita = new fruita();
            Fruita.durada = 0;
            Fruita.valorNutritiu = 9;
            Fruita.x = 0;
            Fruita.y = 0;

            pintaMarc();

            PintarCuc1rPosicio(ref body.cXanelles, ref cucx, ref cucy, ref cuc);

            while (!final)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                    {
                        Direccions.direcció = 'W';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                    {
                        Direccions.direcció = 'E';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        Direccions.direcció = 'N';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        Direccions.direcció = 'S';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    {
                        final = true;
                    }

                }
                while (Fruita.durada == 0)
                {
                    PosarFruita(ref Fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafalsa, ref cucx, ref cucy);
                }

                PodrirFruita(ref Augment, ref Fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafalsa, ref cucx, ref cucy);

                MovimentCUC(ref Augment, ref cucx, ref cucy, ref cuc, ref Direccions.direcció);

                colisio = Colisions(ref cuc, ref cucx, ref cucy);

                if (!colisio)
                {
                    final = true;
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);

            }

        }
        public static void pintaMarc()
        {

            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("╔");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(75, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("╗");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(75, 25);
            Console.WriteLine("╝");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 25);
            Console.WriteLine("╚");

            for (int x = 2; x < 75; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 2);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }
            for (int x = 2; x < 75; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 25);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }
            for (int y = 3; y < 25; y++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1, y);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(75, y);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
            }
        }
        public static void PintarCuc1rPosicio(ref int cXanelles, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy, ref CoordsCuc cuc)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
            Console.WriteLine("☻");

            for (int x = 0; x < cuc.llargada; x++)
            {
                cXanelles = cXanelles + 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cXanelles, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cucx[x] = cXanelles;
                cucy[x] = cuc.cY;
            }

        }
        public static void MovimentCUC(ref int Augment, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref char direcció)
        {

            if (Augment != 0)
            {
                cuc.llargada++;
                Augment--;
            }
            for (int x = cuc.llargada; x > 0; x--)
            {

                cucx[x] = cucx[x - 1];
                cucy[x] = cucy[x - 1];
            }
            cucx[0] = cuc.cX;
            cucy[0] = cuc.cY;
            if (direcció == 'W')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cX--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");

            }
            if (direcció == 'E')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cX++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }
            if (direcció == 'N')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cY--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }
            if (direcció == 'S')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cY++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(cucx[cuc.llargada], cucy[cuc.llargada]);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            for (int x = 0; x < cuc.llargada; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cucx[x], cucy[x]);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
            }
        }
        public static bool Colisionsf(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref fruita fruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool minitruex = false;
            bool minitruey = false;
            //Fruita
            if (fruita.x == cuc.cX & fruita.y == cuc.cY)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
            {
                if (fruita.x == cucx[i])
                {
                    minitruex = true;
                }
                if (fruita.y == cucy[i])
                {
                    minitruey = true;
                }
                if (minitruex == minitruey & minitruex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
        public static bool Colisions(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool colisio = false;

            //Colisio Parets
            if (74 == cuc.cX || 25 == cuc.cY || 2 == cuc.cX || 2 == cuc.cY)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //Colisio Cos
            for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
            {
                if (cuc.cX == cucx[i])
                {
                    colisio = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (cuc.cY == cucy[i])
                {
                    colisio = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return colisio;

        }

        public static void PosarFruita(ref fruita fruita, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int duradafruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool Comprovaciocolisio = false;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            while (!Comprovaciocolisio)
            {
                fruita.x = rnd.Next(2, 75);
                fruita.y = rnd.Next(3, 25);
                Comprovaciocolisio = Colisionsf(ref cuc, ref fruita, ref cucx, ref cucy);
            }

            fruita.valorNutritiu = 9;
            fruita.durada = 60;
            duradafruita = fruita.durada;

            //return;

        }

        public static void PodrirFruita(ref int Augment, ref fruita fruita, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int duradafruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {

            if ((cuc.cX == fruita.x) & (cuc.cY == fruita.y))
            {
                Augment = Augment + fruita.valorNutritiu;
                PosarFruita(ref fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafruita, ref cucx, ref cucy);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(fruita.x, fruita.y);
                Console.WriteLine(fruita.valorNutritiu);
                duradafruita--;

                if (duradafruita == (fruita.durada - 6))
                {

                    fruita.durada = fruita.durada - 6;
                    fruita.valorNutritiu--;

                    if (duradafruita == 0)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(fruita.x, fruita.y);
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            //return;
        }

    }
}
```

Ok, creo que el principal problema lo tengo aquí:

```
public static bool Colisions(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
{
    bool colisio = false;

    //Colisio Parets
    if (74 == cuc.cX || 25 == cuc.cY || 2 == cuc.cX || 2 == cuc.cY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Colisio Cos
    for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
    {
        if (cuc.cX == cucx[i])
        {
            colisio = true;
            break;
        }
        if (cuc.cY == cucy[i])
        {
            colisio = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return colisio;

}
```

Aquí tengo principalmente dos problemas, al tirar hacia la izquierda y chocar contra la pared, lo hace un bloque antes de lo que debería, no como en las otras paredes que parece que llega a comerse  un bloque. Y el último problema, es que la serpiente no choca consigo misma y eso es porque creo que no entra debidamente al if de la última función citada. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Por cierto, creo que fallo un poco al tener dos arrays declarados en main... Si alguien ve alguna forma de mejorar el código que lo deje por ahí también, de nuevo gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, el código ha quedado así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cuc
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Coords
        {
            public int cXanelles;
        }
        public struct CoordsCuc
        {
            public int cX, cY;
            public char direcció;
            public int llargada;
        }

        public struct fruita
        {
            public int x, y, durada, augment, valorNutritiu;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool colisioP = false, colisioC = false, final = false;
            int Augment = 0;
            int duradafalsa = 0;
            int[] cucx = new int[1800];
            int[] cucy = new int[1800];

            CoordsCuc cuc = new CoordsCuc();
            cuc.cX = 37;
            cuc.cY = 12;
            cuc.llargada = 4;
            cuc.direcció = 'W';

            Coords body = new Coords();
            body.cXanelles = 37;

            fruita Fruita = new fruita();
            Fruita.durada = 0;
            Fruita.valorNutritiu = 9;
            Fruita.x = 0;
            Fruita.y = 0;
            Fruita.augment = 0;

            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            pintaMarc();

            PintarCuc1rPosicio(ref body.cXanelles, ref cucx, ref cucy, ref cuc);

            while (!final)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direcció = 'W';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direcció = 'E';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direcció = 'N';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direcció = 'S';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    {
                        final = true;
                    }

                }
                while (Fruita.durada == 0)
                {
                    PosarFruita(ref Fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafalsa, ref cucx, ref cucy);
                }

                PodrirFruita(ref Fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafalsa, ref cucx, ref cucy);

                MovimentCUC(ref Fruita, ref cucx, ref cucy, ref cuc, ref cuc.direcció);

                colisioC = ColisionsC(ref cuc, ref cucx, ref cucy);
                colisioP = ColisionsP(ref cuc, ref cucx, ref cucy);

                if (!colisioC || !colisioP)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Has mort");
                    final = true;
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);

            }

        }
        public static void pintaMarc()
        {

            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("╔");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(75, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("╗");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(75, 25);
            Console.WriteLine("╝");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 25);
            Console.WriteLine("╚");

            for (int x = 2; x < 75; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 2);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }
            for (int x = 2; x < 75; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 25);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }
            for (int y = 3; y < 25; y++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1, y);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(75, y);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
            }
        }
        public static void PintarCuc1rPosicio(ref int cXanelles, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy, ref CoordsCuc cuc)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
            Console.WriteLine("☻");

            for (int x = 0; x < cuc.llargada; x++)
            {
                cXanelles = cXanelles + 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cXanelles, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cucx[x] = cXanelles;
                cucy[x] = cuc.cY;
            }

        }
        public static void MovimentCUC(ref fruita fruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref char direcció)
        {

            if (fruita.augment != 0)
            {
                cuc.llargada++;
                fruita.augment--;
            }
            for (int x = cuc.llargada; x > 0; x--)
            {

                cucx[x] = cucx[x - 1];
                cucy[x] = cucy[x - 1];
            }
            cucx[0] = cuc.cX;
            cucy[0] = cuc.cY;
            if (direcció == 'W')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cX--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");

            }
            if (direcció == 'E')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cX++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }
            if (direcció == 'N')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cY--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }
            if (direcció == 'S')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
                cuc.cY++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cuc.cX, cuc.cY);
                Console.WriteLine("☻");
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(cucx[cuc.llargada], cucy[cuc.llargada]);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            esborraArray(cuc, ref cucx, ref cucy);

            for (int x = 0; x < cuc.llargada; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cucx[x], cucy[x]);
                Console.WriteLine("█");
            }
        }
        public static bool Colisionsf(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref fruita fruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool trueX = false;
            bool trueY = false;

            if (fruita.x == cuc.cX & fruita.y == cuc.cY)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
            {
                if (fruita.x == cucx[i])
                {
                    trueX = true;
                }
                if (fruita.y == cucy[i])
                {
                    trueY = true;
                }
                if (trueX == trueY & trueX)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
        public static bool ColisionsP(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool colisio = false;


            if (74 == cuc.cX || 25 == cuc.cY || 2 == cuc.cX || 2 == cuc.cY)
            {
                return colisio;
            }
            else
            {
                colisio = true;
            }

            return colisio;

        }

        public static bool ColisionsC(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool trueX = false;
            bool trueY = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
            {
                if (cuc.cX == cucx[i])
                {
                    trueX = true;
                }
                if (cuc.cY == cucy[i])
                {
                    trueY = true;
                }
                if (trueX == trueY & trueX)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }

        public static void esborraArray(CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucX, ref int[] cucY)
        {
            cucX[cuc.llargada] = 0;
            cucY[cuc.llargada] = 0;
        }

        public static void PosarFruita(ref fruita fruita, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int duradafruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool Comprovaciocolisio = false;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            while (!Comprovaciocolisio)
            {
                fruita.x = rnd.Next(2, 75);
                fruita.y = rnd.Next(3, 25);
                Comprovaciocolisio = Colisionsf(ref cuc, ref fruita, ref cucx, ref cucy);
            }

            fruita.valorNutritiu = 9;
            fruita.durada = 60;
            duradafruita = fruita.durada;

        }

        public static void PodrirFruita(ref fruita fruita, ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int duradafruita, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {

            if ((cuc.cX == fruita.x) & (cuc.cY == fruita.y))
            {
                fruita.augment += fruita.valorNutritiu;
                PosarFruita(ref fruita, ref cuc, ref duradafruita, ref cucx, ref cucy);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(fruita.x, fruita.y);
                Console.WriteLine(fruita.valorNutritiu);
                duradafruita--;

                if (duradafruita == (fruita.durada - 6))
                {

                    fruita.durada = fruita.durada - 6;
                    fruita.valorNutritiu--;

                    if (duradafruita == 0)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(fruita.x, fruita.y);
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Y así la función de colisiones:

```
 public static bool ColisionsC(ref CoordsCuc cuc, ref int[] cucx, ref int[] cucy)
        {
            bool trueX = false;
            bool trueY = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < cuc.llargada; i++)
            {
                if (cuc.cX == cucx[i])
                {
                    trueX = true;
                }
                if (cuc.cY == cucy[i])
                {
                    trueY = true;
                }
                if (trueX == trueY & trueX)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }
```